# Did we require to rename SHIELD to S.H.I.E.L.D?

Tags: discussion

Marvel's S.H.I.E.L.D. is always presented with dots because its a short for of Strategic Homeland Intervention, Enforcement and Logistics Division. But here we have questions and answer with S.H.I.E.L.D. or as SHIELD. Do we need to standardize it to S.H.I.E.L.D.?

Comment: I remember when it was just plain old Supreme Headquarters, International Espionage, Law-Enforcement Division.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think standardizing the name in the question and answer text should be a priority, so long as the tags are consistent.

Tags are the site's way of providing efficient searching for subjects, and that should be the focus.

While obviously it would be nice to have the content of every question and answer about *Agents* use the same orthography, I don't think it's necessary to go making edits for that purpose alone--we *are* told not to make picky edits that don't improve the post's content.

If you're editing a post for something else, go ahead and fix the punctuation, but so long as the tags are accurate it's not a big deal.

Comment: But standardize name help in searching. I mean if i search by **agent of S.H.I.E.L.D.** i get less result then searching by name **agent of SHIELD**.

Comment: @AnkitSharma That's why we should be sure to standardize the tags, as they're the primary search tool.

Comment: But we can add **.** in tag which is essential part of S.H.I.E.L.D. name bcoz its a short form. So why not give correct name in question answers?

Comment: This depends on what a site user would be more likely to type when searching tags.  Are they likely to type it with the '.'s or without them?

Comment: I go "without" because in the show itself they do say the word "Shield", rather than the letters

Comment: I type it without because it's just a hell of a lot easier. SHIELD is an easy word to type, having to add in a "." after every letter slows me down a lot. Tags aren't supposed to include punctuation, anyway...